# HazelcastInstance bean - what is the proper destroy-method?

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, blueprint-osgi, spring-bean

This is a question about how to define a `destroy-method` on a `HazelcastInstance` bean definition.

Since hazelcast 1.9, the `HazelcastInstance.shutdown()` method became [deprecated](http://www.hazelcast.com/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#shutdown%28%29).

Now, it seems that the following is not possible - below is a bean definition from OSGI blueprint (which defines beans in a similar way, but not exactly the same way, as spring):

```
<bean id="hazelcastInstance" class="com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast"
      factory-method="newInstance" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <argument ref="hazelcastConfig"/>
</bean>
```

The proper way to shut down the hazelcastInstance via code would be like this:

```
    hazelcastInstance.getLifecycleService().shutdown();
```

...however it isn't possible to declare `destroy-method="getLifecycleService().shutdown()"` in my bean definition. I need a simple (public, void) destroy method.

Without wanting to write a wrapper class, is there an appropriate way do destroy my hazelcast Instance via a destroy-method?

Note: HazelcastClient does offer the [shutdownAll](http://www.hazelcast.com/javadoc/com/hazelcast/client/HazelcastClient.html#shutdownAll%28%29) method, so `destroy-method="shutdownAll"` is indeed possible in that case.

Why isn't the same possible with HazelcastInstance? Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't see any other way out than creating a wrapper class. I'll ask if the HazelcastInstance.shutdown() method doesn't need to be removed; just can forward to the LifecycleService. The shutdown method is the method I use most often and perhaps the api can be simplified a bit.

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to de-deprecate (inprecate?) that one.

Comment: We have re-added the shutdown method on the HazelcastInstance.

Comment: Awesome, which release version will include this change?